# Loading Textures in Init()

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

Trying to texture a skybox and loading the textures fine with "ImageLoader::createJPG", which loads a texture file in the proper format and my code textures it to the polygons just fine if I load them in every display loop (which is obviously an awful performance hit.)

But when I try the same code in init() just to load them once, display doesn't even think they exist (I just end up with a cube of the default colour.)

GLuint skyFront; etc. is declared before anything else at the top of the file just after the #includes.

No amount of enables or texParameters seems to make init() want to load the textures. Any ideas?

```
GLuint skyTop;
GLuint skyFront;
GLuint skyBack;
GLuint skyBottom;
GLuint skyLeft;
GLuint skyRight;


void display()                                  
{
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

glLoadIdentity();




glTranslatef(0,0,-0.6);
glTranslatef(0, -0.4, -1);        


glPushMatrix(); 
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
glDisable(GL_BLEND);
//glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
//glTranslatef(camPos.x, camPos.y,camPos.z);
//glDepthMask(GL_FALSE);
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
//draw skybox
glLoadIdentity();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glTranslatef(0.0,-2.0,-20.0);
        GLuint skyTop = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/top.jpg");
        GLuint skyBottom = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/bottom.jpg");
        GLuint skyLeft = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/left.jpg");
        GLuint skyFront = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/front.jpg");
        GLuint skyRight = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/right.jpg");
        GLuint skyBack = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/back.jpg");

        //FRONT
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyFront);
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(-SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);       //A
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(-SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);      //B
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);       //C
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);        //D
            glEnd();

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, skyLeft);
            //LEFT
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);        //D
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE);       //C
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, -SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE);        //E
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex3f(SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE, SKYBOXSIZE);     //F
            glEnd();
```

etc. etc.

edit:

init() code looks like this:

```
void init()
{
glewInit()

    GLuint skyFront = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/front.jpg"); //load the texture, damnit

glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);                      

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

//light position and colour
GLfloat light_position[] = { 0.0, 0.0, 20.0,0.0 };
GLfloat white_light[] = {0.8,0.8,0.8,0.0};
GLfloat diff_light[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0};
GLfloat spec_light[] = {1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0};
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, white_light);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diff_light);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, spec_light);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);


//ambient light
GLfloat ambient[] = {0.3,0.3,0.3};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);

//diffuse material component
GLfloat diff[] = {0.6,0.6,0.6};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE, diff);

//specular material component
GLfloat WhiteSpec[] = {1,1,1};
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, WhiteSpec);

GLfloat shininess = 50;
glMaterialf(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, shininess);

//ENABLE LIGHTING AND DEPTH TEST
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);




glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

cout << " loading model " << endl;
if(objLoader.loadModel("../TestModels/hummer.obj", model))//returns true if the model is loaded, puts the model in the model parameter
{
    cout << " model loaded " << endl;       

    //if you want to translate the object to the origin of the screen,
    //first calculate the centre of the object, then move all the vertices
    //back so that the centre is on the origin.
    model.calcCentrePoint();
    model.centreOnZero();


    model.calcVertNormalsUsingOctree();  //the method will construct the octree if it hasn't already been created.


    //turn on VBO by setting useVBO to true in 3dmodel.cpp default constructor - only permitted on 8 series cards and higher
    if(!model.useImmediateMode || model.useVBO)
    {
        model.initDrawElements();
    }
    if(model.useVBO)
    {
        model.initVBO();
        model.deleteVertexFaceData();
    }

}
else
{
    cout << " model failed to load " << endl;
}
}
```

And all the rest of the GL commands go through and even the model I load goes through fine. TexPerameters and so on are defined in ImageLoader, yeah..

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the code which is actually failing - there is no init() function. Best guess without seeing the actual code is that the GL context is perhaps not valid during init(). Does other GL initialisation happen in that function? The TexParameter settings are presumably in the ImageLoader() or it likely wouldn't function in the form given either.

Comment: Updated with init.. Don't know why I didn't in the first place. Other GL initialisation happens in the function and yeah, the TexParameter settings are in ImageLoader..

Comment: Yeah. Is there any reason that calling them in init() alone wouldn't set the global variables?

Comment: Well in the code you've posted, you've declared a local variable with the same name. So your posted coded is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are global:

```
GLuint skyTop;
GLuint skyFront;
GLuint skyBack;
GLuint skyBottom;
GLuint skyLeft;
GLuint skyRight;
```

But this sets a local:

```
void init()
{
    glewInit()

    GLuint skyFront = ImageLoader::createJPG("../TestModels/front.jpg"); //load the texture, damnit
```

You need to not re-declare the skyFront variable, and use the global instead.

Comment: Thank you! That's one dumb mistake out of the way.

Comment: And now it works (after I the init() function call back in the right place >.<). Thank you!